# Drawbacks to using svg images in websites?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

I've been reading articles on svg images and why they're great to use, scalable, usually smaller in size, easily interpreted by browsers, etc. So I was looking at my website design and saw that I could convert almost all my assets into svg images (logo, borders, every icon, I can even convert some static images to svg using Adobe Illustrator's Image Trace), and before I go ahead and do that, I'm wondering if I'm placing myself into any traps by having so much of my site using svg. I'll be using NextJS for my project.

- Are there any drawbacks to using svg at all?
- If my converted svg image is slightly larger than its jpeg/png counterpart (say 300kb svg vs 200kb png), is it still better to use the svg?
- Is there a drawback to using very complex and large svg files of 1mb or more?

Comment: SVGs should be used for things like icons and logos. PNGs should be used for things like photographs or other large images that are considered "content" and not "UI".

Comment: Make sure you're not just wrapping bitmap images in the SVG file format via the image element - there's no advantage to doing that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SVGs aren't likely to be photorealistic. They require tooling to create vs clicking a button on your phone camera. Understanding that SVGs aren't a replacement for PNGs, JPGs, etc., but another option is important.
2. It depends. If you will never resize the image, go with what's smaller. SVGs can be resized without loss of visual fidelity because it's just math powering them. So, if you have a responsive site and the image will resize a good amount, go with the SVG every time.
3. Any large image comes with the same drawbacks: performance. SVGs are less likely to be big images than a JPG, though. Again, because they're just a text file that an interpreter (browser, etc.) understands.

So, like everything in programming, they're usage depends on your need.